# Разница между gap и grid-gap(Grid Layout)

Tags: css

В чем разница между **gap и grid-gap** в **Grid Layout(CSS**), ведь результат один и тот же.

Comment: Никакой, просто в css3 grid-gap переименовали в gap

Comment: Спасибо, теперь ясно =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модуль CSS Grid Layout первоначально определил свойство как grid-gap, впоследствии оно с приходом CSS3 заменяется на свойство gap. Однако для поддержки более широкого круга браузеров, которые реализовали свойство grid-gap, а не gap, необходимо использовать свойство grid-gap.

Источники: [раз](https://basicweb.ru/css/css_pr_grid-gap.php), [два](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/gap), [три](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-gap.asp)

Comment: Значит для более лучшей совместимости лучше писать полное имя grid-gap?

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский по идее grid-gap = gap, но grid-gap использовался теми браузерами (и их версиями), которые использовали CSS до ввода CSS3 и замены на gap, так что, если Вам важна совместимость со старыми версиями браузеров, можете писать первый вариант.

Comment: Под первым вариантом вы имели в виду grid-gap?

Comment: Абсолютно верно, именно grid-gap